# How to Correct Landsat 8 Imagery with TOA Reflectance >1 and <0?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, reflectance

I recently downloaded Landsat 8 T1 imagery and have ran into some difficulties during pre-processing. I applied the TOA reflectance and sun elevation corrections to Bands 2,3,4,5,6 using ArcGIS's raster calculator after clipping each band to match the extent of my study area.

However, Band 5 (NIR) has a minimum value of -0.00916394 and the maximum values of my bands exceed 1 (1.18148 - 1.34319). How do I got about bringing my values back into the 0-1 range?

I read elsewhere that values in this range are typical of Landsat 8 imagery, but I cannot find a guide that walks me through the necessary corrections.

Comment: There is no correction per se, just truncate the values [<0 = 0 & > 1 = 1]

Comment: Thank you, but I would I write that as an expression in the raster calculator?

Comment: Yes, look at the "con" tool and statements. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/con-.htm

Comment: Using the example on the page you shared I made the expression: Con(B2_BLUEREF, 1 "Value >=1") However, it is still unclear to me what the input conditional and true raster should be. I was able to run Con, but it produced no output. I used B2_BLUEREF for both the conditional and true raster.

Comment: `Con("B2_BLUEREF" >1, 1, "B2_BLUEREF") ` then similar for <0 and merge them. Or wrap up both in a single statement `Con("B2_BLUEREF" >1, 1, Con("B2_BLUEREF" < 0, 0, "B2_BLUEREF") )`